# How do I mock a method in JUnit using Mockito or PowerMockito that contains a File, and BufferedReader

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I've already seen some threads suggesting not to Mock a File but I might have to given my current situation.

I am writing a method that has no parameters. The point of the method is to build a String path if it is available, after that take the String path and create a File, then read the File using a BufferedReader to return a list of Strings.

I'm wondering how would I go about writing the test case for this situation

The method is also uses Guice `@Provides`, `@Singleton`, `@Named()`

Comment: Could you please say, why you can't place the test file to your test resources directory?

Comment: the test file is in a different folder in my directory that is reserved for test files but even then I'm not sure if it is possible to Mock or Powermock the method I want to test, do you know if it is possible to test a method in a class that does not have a constructor, nor does it have any class wide variables. All the files and bufferedReaders my method makes are local to the method itself

Comment: Ok. Are you able to share the code? It will be very helpful. 

Nevertheless, if I understood right, you want to test a private method? Also, as I understood, you want to set the object field manually (cause you have only no-arg constructor). Yes, you can do it if reflection, but I would recommend you to think about your code organization. Maybe you don't need to test a private method? Or should extract it to another class..